# How do I show plot zoomed in?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I'm using matplotlib to show a plot with `%matplotlib widget` in jupyter lab. Almost every time I show the plot, next thing I have to do is zoom in and examine one of the sections of the plot. I would like to be able to show the plot zoomed into that section, and if I want to examine the rest of the plot, as I sometimes do, I would press back button and see all of it.

This is similar to showing subplot with relevant data or using `plt.xlim`, except I would like to do it in a single plot so the data I'm looking at can occupy more screen space, and `plt.xlim` just shows relevant stretch of data without possibility to zoom out again.

How do I do this is jupyter lab?

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. Since you use `%matplotlib widget`, then the drawn chart is interactive. You can use the buttons on the left edge to zoom in the figure.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is skip using `%matplotlib widget` and instead create a giant version of your plot at high resolution, save it as an image, and open the saved image outside of the notebook with an image viewer. Viewing directly inside a notebook is severely restricted by screen real estate limits of the notebook it is embedded in and often is best thought of as a preview. Or if you just want to plot a portion of the plot, also dispense with using %matplotlib widget and use the  settings you discuss to tell matplotlib what you want. Or a combination of that sort.

Comment: Or you may be interested in [sidecar](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar). Or program ipywidgets to change the views as you describe. Or just post one cell with the zoomed in and the next cell with the zoomed out and scroll up and down. Keep in mind you can render output side by side: `View -> Render side by side` in JupyterLab.